# reCaptcha v3 - send Form data to another file

Tags: php, jquery, forms, redirect, recaptcha-v3

Just starting playing with recaptcha and need to send form data to another file for further processing (sending to CRM). Before the captcha was implemented the form had the property action='post-sign-up', which was sending the data without problem to the post-sign-up.php.
But now with recaptcha I understand the form action property needs to be empty, and I can't figure out a way of sending the data to the other file after verifying that captcha.

When completing the form (pressing submit) the captcha is triggered. If verification fails it would show the error, but if it succeeds I need the form data to be submitted and sent to another file which does some further processing.

In other words:

- user completes the form
- user press submit
- captcha verification occurs
- if captcha is not ok, error will be shown (redirect to the same page)
- if captcha is ok, the form data should be submitted to another file for further processing
  (post-sign-up.php)
- if post-sign-up is ok, it will show the thank you page (post-sign-up-success.php)

Thank you!

This is only client-side (no server)
**sign-up.php**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6Lc3UZkeAAAAAMt6wcA-bYjLenFZPGv3K5AqfvuQ"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/jquery.deparam.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/jquery.urlparam.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<?php
    define("RECAPTCHA_V3_SECRET_KEY", "6Lc3UZkeAAAAAIG8bVZDpkheOxM56AiMnIKYRd6z");

    if(isset($_POST['token'])) 
    {
      if (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email']) {
        $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $firstName = filter_var($_POST['firstName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      } else {
         // set error message and redirect back to form...
          header('location: sign-up.php');
        exit;
      }
      
      $token = $_POST['token'];
      $action = $_POST['action'];
      
      // call curl to POST captcha request
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('secret' => RECAPTCHA_V3_SECRET_KEY, 'response' => $token)));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      $arrResponse = json_decode($response, true);
        
      // verify the response
      if($arrResponse["success"] == '1' && $arrResponse["action"] == $action && $arrResponse["score"] >= 0.7) {
          // valid submission
          $captchaError = false;
          // Maybe here I can send all the form data to another file which does some further processing          
      } else {
          // spam submission
          $captchaError = true;
      }
    }
?>

<section class="lc-layout-component border bank-font">
    <div class="lc-content component-padding gutters">

        <section class="cc-column-component regular-grid">
            <?php if (isset($this) && $this->wasError()) { ?>
                <div class="error">
                    <p><?php echo $this->getErrorMessage(); ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php
                  }?>
                    <!--old action: /post-sign-up -->
                    <form id="bank-form" class="form clear one-full cf-contact-form" action="?" method="POST" data-tracking="contact_sales"> 
                      <div>                         
                              <label class="label mandatory bank-color bank-label" for="firstName">First Name</label>
                              <input id="firstName" value="Pepe" type="text" class="one-full bank-color-grey bank-input" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off" data-validate="true" data-type="text" data-min="3" value="<?php isset($this) ? print $this->getFirstName() : print ''; ?>">
                              <br/>
                              <label class="label mandatory bank-color bank-label" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                              <input id="lastName" value="Chanches" type="text" class="one-full bank-color-grey bank-input" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off" data-validate="true" data-type="text" data-min="3" value="<?php isset($this) ? print $this->getLastName() : print ''; ?>">
                              <br/>
                              <label class="label mandatory bank-color bank-label" for="company">Company</label>
                              <input id="company" value="Pepe Ltd" type="text" class="one-full bank-color-grey bank-input" name="company"  placeholder="Company" autocomplete="off" data-validate="true" data-type="text" data-min="3" value="<?php isset($this) ? print $this->getCompany() : print ''; ?>">
                              <br/>
                              <label class="label mandatory bank-color bank-label" for="email">Email</label>
                              <input value="asdf@asdf.com" id="email" type="text" class="one-full bank-color-grey bank-input" name="email" placeholder="Email"  autocomplete="off" data-validate="true" data-type="email" value="<?php isset($this) ? print $this->getEmail() : print ''; ?>">
                              <br/>
                              <label class="label mandatory bank-color bank-label" for="phone">Phone</label>
                              <input id="phone" value="+4565464565"  type="text" class="one-full bank-color-grey bank-input" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"  autocomplete="off" data-validate="true" data-type="phone" value="<?php isset($this) ? print $this->getPhone() : print ''; ?>">
                              <br/>
                              <label class="label bank-color bank-label" for="referredBy">Referred by </label>
                              <input id="referredBy" value="Pepa" type="text" class="one-full bank-color-grey bank-input" name="referredBy" placeholder="Referred By"  autocomplete="off" value="<?php isset($this) ? print $this->getCashManager() : print ''; ?>">
                      </div>
                        <div class="row inline one-full">
                        <br/>
                                <!-- <div class="g-recatpcha" data-sitekey="6Lc3UZkeAAAAAMt6wcA-bYjLenFZPGv3K5AqfvuQ"></div> -->
                                <button type="submit"
                                        value="submit"
                                        >
                                        <a>Submit form</a>
                                </button>

                            <div class="field inline one-full">
                            <br/>
                                <?php 
                                    isset($arrResponse["score"]) && $captchaError == true && print 'error. Please try again later '; 
                                    print ' score: ';
                                    print $arrResponse["score"];                                    
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">
                        </div>
                    </form>
            </section>
    </div>
</section>
<script>
    $('#bank-form').submit(function(event) {
        console.log('subtmitting');
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        console.log(email);
        var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
        console.log(firstName);
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('6Lc3UZkeAAAAAMt6wcA-bYjLenFZPGv3K5AqfvuQ', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
                $('#bank-form').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="' + token + '">');
                $('#bank-form').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">');
                $('#bank-form').unbind('submit').submit();
            });;
        });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: _"if captcha is ok, the form data should be submitted to another file for further processing (post-sign-up.php)"_ - why don't you just _include_ `post-sign-up.php` into the current script, _if_ the captcha validation was successful?

Comment: you mean like this?  
`if($arrResponse["success"] == '1' && $arrResponse["action"] == $action && $arrResponse["score"] >= 0.7) {`  
  
`// valid submission`    
  
`include '.post-sign-up.php';`

Comment: Maybe without the dot in front of the file name, but other than that, yes.